# Correct grammar with LIKE condition in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, grammar

With SQLite I can:

```
select my_column from my_table where substr(word,1,1) like '%I%';
```

so I'll have all the string results whose first character is I. But now I want to have results whose first character is I and F and J. I have tried:

```
select my_column from my_table where substr(word,1,1) like '%I%'&'%F%'&'%J%';
```

but that doesn't work.

What grammar should I use to find results with those first letters?

Comment: Try `select my_column from my_table where substr(word,1,1) IN ('%I%', '%F%', '%J%');`. Also see: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: thanks sebastian! but it doesn't work, nothing comes out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the right answer: `SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE upper(substr(word,1,1)) IN ('I', 'F', 'J');`

Comment: Sorry again. What if i have to use LIKE? it should be either "i" or "I", not just "I". Thanks again!

Comment: i've accepted it! in fact my query is: select word from en4k where upper(substr(word,1,1)) in ('F ','G ','H ','I ','J') and upper(substr(word,2,1)) in ('K ','L ','M ','N ','O') and upper(substr(word,3,1)) in ('A ','B ','C ','D ','E'). But the word "job" simply doesn't come out. If skip the "and upper(substr(word,3,1)) in ('A ','B ','C ','D ','E')" then thw word is there. Why is that?

Comment: so i think i have to use LIKE, is it?

Comment: First of all: You should have asked your question differently. Secondly, please use the edit function of the comments and thirdly: You have a space in your strings in the IN section. 'B ' should be 'B', shouldn't it?

Comment: i'm a rookie so... 1. I thought with LIKE condition it returns both I and i? 2. this is first time i ask question, will u kindly tell me why use edit?  3. about the space: thx for the heads up! That's the reason why. Danke!

Comment: I know you are a rookie, that's why I told you. It is unclear what exactly you want to search so it's hard to tell from this point if you can use LIKE. You edit comments and answers to aggregate information. Good that it is working now! Gern geschehen!